# MAAS. Adding nodes

Tags: networking, server, juju, maas

Can anybody help me with MAAS installation? I installed it on 1 of my computers, configured DHCP server and now 3 PCs are in their own private network. I tried to add node via PXE image, but "Can not apply stage final, no datasource found! Likely bad things to come!" error comes after giving me option to log in. Then I tried to add node via web interface, but after adding it node's status is always "commisioning". So what should I do know? Any help is appreciated. Thank you
P.S. English is not my native language, sorry for any type of errors.

Answer (score 1):

You need to log in to the maas server via ssh and run:

```
maas-cli <user-id> nodes acquire hostname=<name-of-server-you-added-in-ui>.
```

Once it's acquired then you will be able to pxe boot it.

Here is an example:

```
oot@Ubuntu1204Server:~# maas-cli root nodes acquire hostname=test1
{
    "status": 6,
    "macaddress_set": [
        {
            "resource_uri": "/MAAS/api/1.0/nodes/node-8bd4730e-e5ef-11e2-9310-fa163e76111f/macs/fa:16:3e:42:4b:46/",
            "mac_address": "fa:16:3e:42:4b:46"
        }
    ],
    "netboot": true,
    "hostname": "test1",
    "power_type": "",
    "system_id": "node-8bd4730e-e5ef-11e2-9310-fa163e76111f",
    "architecture": "amd64/generic",
    "tag_names": [],
    "resource_uri": "/MAAS/api/1.0/nodes/node-8bd4730e-e5ef-11e2-9310-fa163e76111f/"
```